# How to programatically set designtime height / width of TDatamodule in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, code-generation, design-time

I generate a TDatamodule with a bunch of TFDQueries that it contains. Then, I save this Datamodule .DFM like so

```
  lFileStream   := TFileStream.Create('Datamodule.dfm', fmCreate);
  lMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  lMemoryStream.WriteComponent(lDataModule);
  lMemoryStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
  ObjectBinaryToText(lMemoryStream, lFileStream);
  lFileStream.Free;
  lMemoryStream.Free;
```

To be user-friendly, I need to set the width and height of this TDatamodule when I generate it. But I cannot use

```
lDatamodule.Width := 500; // Does not compile
lDatamodule.Height := 500; // Does not compile
```

Because Width and Height are registered design time properties. A similar strategy allowing to set the designtime Left and Top properties of TComponents is done using the DesignInfo property as such

```
procedure BootyShakin;
  var
    NewDesignInfo       : LongRec;
  begin
    NewDesignInfo.Lo := Word(100);
    NewDesignInfo.Hi := Word(100);
    lComponent.DesignInfo := Longint(NewDesignInfo);
  end;
```

I am looking for an analogous solution for setting the design time width and height of a TDatamodule before it is saved to .DFM

Comment: I precised that this had to be done by code @MartynA

Comment: "WIdth" and "Height" are design time properties only, they're not directly accessible by code. @MartynA

Comment: A data module is not visible at run time, so what is the issue?

Comment: @MartynA did you downvote the question? Width and Height are custom property editors registered with the RegisterProperty. That's why you see em on the design time editor. They do not exist at runtime.

Comment: This is a code generation issue. The datamodule .PAS and .DFM are --generated--. Thus the need to set it's design time properties.@penarthur66

Comment: @penarthur66 Please see updated question

Comment: set the DesignSize.x and DesignSize.y before save?
DesignSize is a public Tpoint

Comment: Thank you @Fritzw

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, corrected.  But I assumed you know about DesignSize and DesignOffset.

Comment: @MartynA Now I do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TDataModule` offers a public property [`DesignSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TDataModule.DesignSize), which is of type `TPoint`.

Documentation says:

> Specifies the design size for the data module at design time.
>   An application should never need to set this value. It controls the size of the data module window at design time.

Despite the documentation does not recommend it - for normal applications, which use the `TDataModule`, I think - you can archieve what you are looking for with this property.

Comment: It looks like @FritzW had the same idea as me at the same time. :-D